# Does keeping Virtual Machine's in "Availability set" will assure it's storage account are placed in different server racks?

Tags: azure, architecture, azure-storage, disk

I was reading article from Microsoft which states as below

> Managed disks are integrated with availability sets to ensure that the disks of VMs in an availability set are sufficiently isolated from each other to avoid a single point of failure. Disks are automatically placed in different storage scale units (stamps). If a stamp fails due to hardware or software failure, only the VM instances with disks on those stamps fail. For example, let's say you have an application running on five VMs, and the VMs are in an Availability Set. The disks for those VMs won't all be stored in the same stamp, so if one stamp goes down, the other instances of the application continue to run.

[image]

So the question is:

1. Is it `single storage unit`? I mean, if that storage unit is down, all VM goes down?
2. If yes, Does `managed disk` is the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Answer to both is Yes. Use Managed Disks with Availability Sets when creating VMs so to avoid Hardware failures within a Zone aka Data Center. Multiple Zones aka multiple Data Centers combine to become an Azure Region. In one region you will have a minimum of 3 zones (data centers) and max has no limit as of now.

Answer (score 1):

Managed disks by design have a high availability (SLA~~99.99%)This is done by providing you with three replicas of your data. If one or even two replicas experience issues, the remaining replicas help ensure persistence of your data and high tolerance against failures.

In fact, It is even better but more expensive, to use managed disks with Availability Zone Option, which protects your apps from a data center failure.. (Which happens!)